# JFrame stuck, i can't move across sreen

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jbutton

I made a frame with some labels and a button on it, created an executable ear and now when i start it i can't move the application on my screen. Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't. I just can't drag the thing..

> ```
>   JFrame frame = new JFrame("Name");
>   frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(260, 160));
>   frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
>
>   JButton exitButton = new JButton("Exit");
>   exitButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
>
>       @Override
>       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
>           System.exit(0);
>       }
>   });
>   frame.add(exitButton, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
>   frame.add(vertBox, BorderLayout.CENTER);
>   frame.setVisible(true);
>   frame.pack();
>   frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
> ```

Any ideas what's wrong? It's really annoying that i can't move it.
P.S. There is a code part that i skipped, where i made the labels and added them

Comment: updates your java libaries

Comment: Which operating system? Maybe the window is too big sometimes?

Comment: You don't have any loops running?

Comment: Did you remember to switch to the Swing thread (SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait) before doing GUI code?

Comment: My libs are up-to-date. Im running on windows 7 x64 and yes, there are some loops in the class that has the jframe, but even when they dont run this happens

Comment: I had the same problem and what @RobinGreen said was the reason - one monitor's vertical resolution is higher than the other's, so I couldn't move the frame out of the smaller monitor.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps (in the code you didn't show) you were disabling your frame through

> frame.setEnabled(false);

PS: I know it has been 2 years since you asked the question, but it might help someone else

Comment: Yup, it's completely fine. Here's [your answer](/review/late-answers/14517796) in Late Answers.